# Understanding C++ member function template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class testclass
{
public:
    template <class T> T item(const std::string& key)
    {
        std::cout << "non-specialized\n";
        return T();
    }
};
```

For the item method I would like to provide a specialization for strings. I try to do this the following way (in testclass.cpp):

```
#include "testclass.h"
#include <iostream>

template<> std::string testclass::item(const std::string& key)
{
    std::cout << "specialized\n";
    return std::reverse(key.begin(), key.end());
}
```

And then I try to call the function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testclass.h"

int main()
{
    testclass t;
    std::string key = "foo";
    t.item<int>(key);
    std::string s = t.item<std::string>(key);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

However, the output is

```
$ ./a.out
non-specialized 
non-specialized
(empty line)
```

What I excepted was

```
$ ./a.out
non-specialized 
specialized
oof
```

How can I do this properly? I am using g++ 4.5.2 to compile the program.

**Edit**:

The solution is the move the whole definition of the specialization of `item` to testclass.h (but not into the class). I had other mistakes in the program, such as not including `<algorithm>` (for reverse), and incorrectly thinking that it would return the reversed string. To achieve the excepted behaviour, the .cpp file is left empty, and the header contents are the following:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class testclass
{
    public:
        template <class T> T item(const std::string& key)
        {
            std::cout << "non-specialized\n";
            return T();
        }
};

template<> std::string testclass::item(const std::string& key)
{
    std::cout << "specialized\n";
    std::string s = key;
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to forward declare the specialized version? You have no way to discover this implementation from main.cpp (it only includes testclass.h). I write it here, cause I'm not sure.

Comment: exactly. Compiler doesn't see the specialization while compiling main.cpp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem boils down to the common problem of not having the templates in the header file. The compiler, when processing `main` does not see the specialization and it generates its own instantiation of the generic template for `std::string`. This is a violation of the ODR, as there are now 2 different specializations for `std::string` in the same program, but the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

The simple solution is to declare/define the specialization in the header so that the compiler can either use it, or at least will know not to generate the specialization from the generic version when processing `main`

Comment: Well the reason I originally moved the specialization into the .cpp file was that the compiler complained about it (`testclass.h:14:18: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class testclass’`). This happens if I have only the declaration of the specialization in the class. If I also put the implementation, it will also have a very ugly template-instantiation error in addition to the above.

Comment: This was the solution, but I had other mistakes, I'm updating the post. Thanks.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: you cannot provide the specialization at class level. Member template function specialiations must be provided at namespace level.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, this is not the whole story.  The explicit specialization of the member template function 'item' must be unique throughout the program.  If you were to create another translation unit that implemented another function that did the same thing as 'main' and linked that into your program, you would get multiple definitions.  You have a couple of alternatives: (1) declare the specialization to be an inline function in the header (not a general solution); (2) declare the specialization in the header and define it in the '.cpp' file (general answer).  This is a great example of the importance of understanding at a fundamental level how compilers and linkers implement the "physical linking" of various C++ constructs.

Comment: Do you really even need to declare the specializaion in the header per (2). I think it's enough to just define it in a .cpp file to which you will link.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn That, in a perfect world, would result in a linker error. main.cpp sees and instantiates the non-specialized version of testclass::item, which conflicts with the specialized version of testclass::item defined in testclass.cpp, and should produce a linker error, but doesn't. Declaring the specialization in the header lets main.cpp know there is a specialization defined somewhere and to use that.