# Template Specialization for member functions

Tags: c++, templates

I've recently discovered `template specialization` in C++.

```
template <typename T>
void    fct(void) {}

template <>
void    fct<int>(void) {}

int main(void) {
  fct<int>();
  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to use template specialization for member functions inside a class.

```
class   MyClass {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    static void fct(void) {}

    template <>
    static void   fct<int>(void) {}
};

int     main(void) {
  MyClass::fct<int>();

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, compiling with `g++` gives me the following error:

```
error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘struct MyClass’
error: template-id ‘toto<int>’ in declaration of primary template
```

I've noticed that doing template specialization works in main scope or in a namespace but not in a struct or in a class.

I've found something on stackoverflow about using a namespace like in the following code:

```
namespace myNameSpace {
  template <typename T>
  void fct(void) {}

  template <>
  void fct<int>(void) {}
}

class   MyClass {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    static void fct(void) {
      myNameSpace::fct<T>();
    }
};

int     main(void) {
  MyClass::fct<int>();

  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to make template specialization with member functions? If not, what is the best way to get around this? Is there a better way than using namespace to get around this?

Comment: Add specialization of member function in global scope as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582548/understanding-c-member-function-template-specialization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the specialization after the class definition:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void fct(void) {}
};

template <>
void MyClass::fct<int>() {}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for: thank you!

Comment: Can someone place the part of the standard that describes this? I know it to be true, but I've never known why :-P.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that this works just the same way and with the same syntax for non-static member functions.